# How to show git email in git bash?

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

By default, the git bash window shows the current branch name next to the path. I want to add the configured git email address.

For example:

- Default: `username@computername MINGW64 /c/repos/repoX (master)`
- Desired:

  - `username@computername MINGW64 /c/repos/repoX (user.1@domain.com -
    master)`
  - `username@computername MINGW64 /c/repos/repoY (user.2@domain.com -
    master)`

I have tried to create a `.bash_profile` file in my home directory and added the following code:

```
parse_git_email() {
    git config user.email 2> /dev/null
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\] $(parse_git_email) \[\033[00m\] $ "
```

This causes two issues:

- The spawned window is now git-cmd instead of MINGW64 (and has another color scheme).
- The email address does not change to the configured email address when I dir to another repository.

So how can I show the configured git email address within the default git bash window?

EDIT:
I use ConEmu, but according to comments it has nothing to do with what I ask.

Comment: Why do you ask about ConEmu? It's completely git-for-windows question.

Comment: @Maximus Is it? It's all confusing for me which parts belong to which system. Should I change the question then?

Comment: You are asking about shell (bash) configuration. This is not related to terminal (ConEmu).